# oracle - how to use foreign key constraints in object types

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an error in the last line in Create table and i dont know how to use foreing key correctly.

```
CREATE TYPE CarType AS OBJECT(
    price_id NUMBER,
    quantity NUMBER
    );

CREATE TABLE Cars(
carid NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
carinfo CarType,
CONSTRAINT car_fk FOREIGN KEY(price_id) REFERENCES Prices(price_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TYPE CarType AS OBJECT(
    price_id NUMBER,
    quantity NUMBER
    );


create table Prices
( cType CarType,
 constraint pk_prices primary key (ctype.price_id) );

CREATE TABLE Cars(
   carid NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
   carinfo cartype,
   CONSTRAINT car_fk FOREIGN KEY(carinfo.price_id) REFERENCES prices(cType.price_id)
);
```

I assumed that you have `Prices` table that you didn't include in your question.